# Emacs and ASP.Net Razor Pages

Tags: package, lsp

I am trying to get .razor and .cshtml pages working in Emacs.

My config is Doom Emacs with (csharp +lsp +dotnet). No issues with the C# code, that all works fine other than absurd refactoring suggestions coming form LSP which I have recently discovered how to silence.

These files (.razor and .cshtml) don't seem to be that well supported by any editors except for JetBrains Rider and maybe Visual Studio for Windows (which I haven't used in ages).

Curious if anyone who is using Emacs as a .Net developer has figured this one out. Would appreciate hearing how you solved it. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to emacs se!  Can you clarify what you mean by "working"?

Comment: Working, in that the .razor and .cshtml syntax is somehow checked. web-mode handles the html bits fine, but has no clue about the c# code mixed in.